# HTML/CSS position-absolute child does not move with position-absolute parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement a sliding carousal in HTML/CSS/Javascript. I have 5 slides, each of which is a div with 100% width and height. In javascript, I line up the 5 divs horizontally, setting the first slide to fill the screen and the other 4 offscreen. I used `.css('left', i * this.slideWidth);` to achieve this.

Each of the slides contains a span containing some text. The position of the span is set to absolute, which should mean it follows the parent slides. However, they are all stacked/overlapping at the same spot on the screen, even though the slides are correctly positioned offscreen.

Here's what it looks like (notice the overlapping text on the top left corner):
[image]

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slide.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "container" id = "container">
        <div class="slide" id="slide1"><span>Slide 1</span></div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide2"><span>Slide 2</span></div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide3"><span>Slide 3</span></div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide4"><span>Slide 4</span></div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide5"><span>Slide 5</span></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.slide {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.slide span {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
}

#slide1 {background: blue;}
#slide2 {background: green;}
#slide3 {background: red;}
```

As you can see in the CSS, both the parent slide and the child span have position set to absolute. Shouldn't that mean the span moves with slide?

Comment: It all appears good, and since it does, you need to provide a _working_ code snippet that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when an element has `position:absolute`, it is positioned absolutely to the ancestor with `position:relative` and not the parent(if parent does not have `position:relative`).

Hence, from your code

```
#container {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.slide {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.slide span {
  position:absolute; /* mistake it is positioned absolute to container and not slide*/
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

So, `span` is not positioned absolute to `slide` but the `container`.

The correct way to do is to add another `div` inside slide with `position:relative` and place the `span` inside it.

```
#container {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.slide {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.slide > div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.slide > div > span {
  position:absolute; 
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class = "container" id = "container">
    <div class="slide" id="slide1"><div><span>Slide 1</span></div></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide2"><div><span>Slide 2</span></div></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide3"><div><span>Slide 3</span></div></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide4"><div><span>Slide 4</span></div></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide5"><div><span>Slide 5</span></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

position:absolute renders dom based on browser dimension. 
if you want the child element to move with parent 
try setting `position:absoulte` to parent and `position:relative` to child element.

in your code, try changing

```
.slide {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.slide span {
  position:relative; //if this is the child to be relative
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your CSS code is working fine, but you have issue with your jQuery code. Your code is not positioning the slides offscreen. Try this code as to understand what I mean. If your jQuery code works fine as you said, your slider would be working good.

```
#slide1 {background: blue;}
#slide2 {background: green; left: -100%;}
#slide3 {background: red; left: -200%;}
#slide4 {background: yellow; left: -300%;}
#slide5 {background: brown; left: -400%;}
```

Comment: Why did you [revert](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49783471/3) the `<!-- language: lang-css -->` [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) language hint? Currently your CSS code is all grey, but proper syntax highlighting would make it easier to read by displaying properties in blue and values in black.